# Deduction guide works in gcc and msvc but rejected by clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, deduction-guide

I am learning about deduction guides in C++. Then I wrote the following code that compiles with gcc and msvc but rejected by clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9176sPxbz)

I want to know which compiler is right here.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

struct Coord
{    
    int x, y;
};

template<int N, int D = 0 >
class CoordArray
{ 
public:
    CoordArray(const Coord(&ref)[N]) 
    {}
};
template<int D, int N> CoordArray() -> CoordArray<N, D>;
CoordArray<3> myCoordArray{{{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}}}; //clang rejects but gcc and msvc accepts
CoordArray myCoordArray2{{{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}}};   //clang rejects but gcc and msvc accepts
```

Clang says:

```
<source>:17:24: error: deduction guide template contains template parameters that cannot be deduced
   17 | template<int D, int N> CoordArray() -> CoordArray<N, D>;
      |                        ^
<source>:17:14: note: non-deducible template parameter 'D'
   17 | template<int D, int N> CoordArray() -> CoordArray<N, D>;
      |              ^
<source>:17:21: note: non-deducible template parameter 'N'
   17 | template<int D, int N> CoordArray() -> CoordArray<N, D>;
      |
```

Comment: I think everyone could be considered correct.  `template<int D, int N> CoordArray() -> CoordArray<N, D>;` is definitely a bad deduction guide, it cannot work.  You don't actually use it so should you get an error or not, IDK, but since it is a bad guide it should be fixed so I don't mind the diagnostic.

Comment: do note that if you remove the bad guide all three compilers will compile the code: https://godbolt.org/z/WoYsszvMs

Comment: @NathanOliver The way I read the standard, clang is correct here and I've tried to sum it up in an answer.

Comment: Alan, is there anything you'd want me to clarify in more detail?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually, the program is **IFNDR**. Note also the IFNDR takes precedence over other rule violations(that would make the program IF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is **ill-formed no diagnostic required** since you're not using the ill-formed deduction guide. So technically, the compilers are not required to give a diagnostic.

From [temp#res.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.5):

> The program is **ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if**:
>
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a templated entity immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct (other than a static_assert-declaration that fails) that does not depend on a template parameter, or

Answer (score 1):

```
deduction-guide :

explicit-specifieropt template-name ( parameter-declaration-clause ) -> simple-template-id ;
```

From the latest [C++23 draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4950.pdf):

> 13.2. Template parameters
>
> - 14. [...] A template parameter of a deduction guide template (13.7.2.3) that does not have a default argument shall be deducible from the parameter-type-list of the deduction guide template.

> 13.7.2.3 Deduction guides
>
> - 3. The same restrictions apply to the parameter-declaration-clause of a deduction guide as in a function declaration
>      (9.3.4.6).

> 9.3.4.6 Functions
>
> - (1.1) — the parameter-type-list is derived from the *parameter-declaration-clause*

In your case, the template parameters of the deduction guide template are *not* deducible from the parameter-type-list, which they shall be for the deduction guide to be valid.

> 4.1.1 General
> (2.3) — Otherwise, if a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule [...], a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message.
>
> *[Note 1 : During template argument deduction and substitution, certain constructs that in other contexts require a
> diagnostic are treated differently; see 13.10.3. — end note]*

13.10.3 doesn't mention deduction *guides* and the ill-formed deduction guide is clearly diagnosable. Clang is therefore correct in issuing a diagnostic message.